# Does the Kindle Fire original have a camera?

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

It may be too late to ask for such a thing... I checked my Kindle Fire 1st generation model and found a camera on the top left of the device. At least, it just looks like the camera on any phone or camera enabled device.

The listing of features on original Kindle Fire shows that there is no camera. Is this something any others have experienced?

Or is it something different from a camera?

I have not tried to download any app to use camera on the device. Any interesting info would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that this is camera? It is more likely a light/proximity sensor...

Comment: Thanks, I just found this on [a blog](http://www.ericbt.com/Blog/169) that describes how to check for the sensor. Your answer is much appreciated.